# Display only related values if not already saved in a one to many many to one relationship Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

my table looks like this

rate table

```
rate  user_id created by
60    1       me
70    2       you
45    3       she
```

users

```
id    name
1    terence
2    luther
5    michael
```

As you see, only michaels id is not in the rate. Now I want to change the form to display only users who's id is not yet in rate table, in this case michael's.

The default RateType Form

```
builder->add('users')
```

This will create dropdown that will showw all users.How would you customise this form so that only user michael will show up?